# Есть ли возможность в одном проекте использовать react.js, react-redux-router и hashHistory?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Здравствуйте, читатели моего вопроса. Я буду, если вы меня направите в верном направлении.

Необходимо реализовать роутинг на клиентской стороне в react приложении. Просят использвать redux и hash в пути.
Например: localhost:8080/#/about

Я впервый раз работаю с React стеком. И пока не нашёл грамотного туториала, где показывается как использовать всё вместе: react, redux, react-redux-router и hashHistory.

У меня реализовано приложение с redux и react-redux-route и redux-thunk, собираю всё это дело webpack-ом. Но после общения с аналитиком понимаю, что мой вариант с

import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

не подходит, и требуется использовать hash, я не смог найти, как использовать hashHistory вместе с redux.

Буду, рад и ответам, что это возможно реализовать и Вам когда-то попадались материалы в интернете на эту тему, если Вам не сложно, напишите какой вопрос вы задавали гуглу, чтобы потом увидеть работающий пример.

Всем спасибо за внимание! Хорошего настроения и продуктивного дня!

Comment: У вас последние версии пакетов? Кажется в этом примере https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux можно просто заменить `history/createBrowserHistory` на `history/createHashHistory`

Comment: ну как, получилось?

Comment: редакс роутер не занимается роутингом приложения... он всего лишь синхронизирует ваш стейет с историей, и всё это ради тайм тревелинга...